# SwiftUI Multiple Modal Sheets won't disappear in code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

This is really confusing and a bit long winded.  I have a SwiftUI app with a 4 button mini tool bar.  Each button spawns a modal sheet to be displayed.  There's a close button in each sheet that doesn't work.  If I swipe down in the sheet to make it disappear, it does disappear and from that point on, everything works fine.  Now for the even weirder part, it works fine in the simulator and if I wrap an Xcode test around it, it works on actual hardware.  If I operate the app manually, that is touch the buttons to open and close the sheets on an iPad, it fails to close the sheet. Also doesn’t trigger `.onDisappear`. Just could use some help.

I'm using an approach like this to attach multiple sheets to the top most view object (a Z stack in this case):

```
ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
    
    case scannerView
    case manSerEntry
    case infoSheet
    case CofASheet
    case mailSheet
        
    var id: Int {
        self.hashValue
    }
}
```

Then in the view struct:

```
struct Row: View {
    @State  var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?
    
    HStack{
        VStack {
            Image("camera")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 60, height: 48)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.activeSheet = ActiveSheet.scannerView
                    print("Camera Button Tapped")
                    Text("Scan")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("APTLightBlue"))
                        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Bold", size: 12))
                }
            VStack {
                Image("info-1")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.activeSheet = ActiveSheet.infoSheet
                    }
                Text("Info")
                    .foregroundColor(Color("APTLightBlue"))
                    .font(.custom("Montserrat-Bold", size: 12))
            }
            VStack {
                Image("document")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.activeSheet = ActiveSheet.CofASheet
                    }
                Text("CofA")
                    .foregroundColor(Color("APTLightBlue"))
                    .font(.custom("Montserrat-Bold", size: 12))
            }
            VStack {
                Image("send")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.activeSheet = ActiveSheet.mailSheet
                    }
                Text("Send")
                    .foregroundColor(Color("APTLightBlue"))
                    .font(.custom("Montserrat-Bold", size: 12))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then the .sheet

```
.sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
    switch item {
    case ActiveSheet.scannerView:
        Button(action: {
            activeSheet = nil
        }, label: {
            Text("ScannerView Close")
                .padding()
        })
        Button(action: {
            activeSheet = ActiveSheet.manSerEntry
            print("Man Serial Entry Open")
            
        }, label: {
            Text("ManSerialSentry Open")
        })
    case ActiveSheet.manSerEntry:
        Button(action: {
            print("Man Serial Entry Close")
            activeSheet = nil
        }, label: {
            Text("ManSerialEntry Close")
        })
    case ActiveSheet.infoSheet:
        Button(action: {
            print("Info Close")
            activeSheet = nil
        }, label: {
            Text("Info Close")
        })
    case ActiveSheet.mailSheet:
        Button(action: {
            print("SendMail Close")
            activeSheet = nil
        }, label: {
            Text("SendMail Close")
        })
    case ActiveSheet.CofASheet:
        Button(action: {
            print("C of A Close")
            activeSheet = nil
        }, label: {
            Text("CofASheet Close")
        })
    }
```

And to make it even worse, I took this same approach and built a little app that only does this and works fine.  I'm at a loss.  So much of the app is commented trying to find this....

Any thoughts are very welcome.

Comment: *it works fine in the simulator and... it works on on actual hardware*, so in which case it does not work?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I updated the write up.  On the simulator, when running as a test or manually, it works fine.  On the device, when run as a test, it works fine.  When run manually on hardware, doesn’t work.

Comment: I have a new clue.  If I completely kill the app on the iPad, i.e. force kill it and restart the bad behavior presents itself.  If I just switch away from the app and come back, it behaves correctly.

Comment: Another new clue.  The view that hosts the sheets is down inside a `navigtationview`.  The style on the nav view is `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`.  If I remove that, it works fine.  Or if I start the navigation further down the tree, it works fine with the `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` modifier.